# Class PDFView is implemented in both

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development. I am getting this problem when I am debugging the iOS app.

> Class PDFView is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/PDFKit.framework/PDFKit
>   (0x129b9a7e8) and
>   /Users/captainajay/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5EE87C45-A6C4-42C6-B652-95AA55E4B031/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F8EBE51A-2259-4D31-8C79-9116034478EF/Notes.app/Notes
>   (0x10dcaf340). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I know this might be the beginner issue. I am beginner to iOS.

I have renamed the PDFView -> PDFNoteView

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'PDFNoteView''

Comment: Try this : change the class name and check.

Comment: Have you used CocoaPods? This might be because you add the same file in multiple targets

Comment: This is beacause of i have custom class with PDFView. In IOS 11 they introduced pdfkit which has same class name in the library files. This is getting conflicted. How do i resolve the issue

Comment: @KSathish change class name.

Comment: I have changed the class name. Again this is giving me one more error. I will add that error here.

Comment: @DixitAkabari I have changed the class name. Now, I am receiving this error

Comment: @KSathish You have to pass the name of the nib file, not the class name.

Comment: I forgot rename the xib file. Now Its started working. Thanks @DixitAkabari for your support.

Comment: @KSathish Happy to Help you :)

Comment: Question can be closed as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._

Comment: Are you using Objective-C (For Swift I don't know)? If yes, that's one of the reason why we like prefixing our classes, to avoid collisions like this one. Look there: http://nshipster.com/namespacing/ It also has a great information about namespace and a good discussion at the end in a link.